# Requesting to an API with python gives me incorrect outputs on Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, api, raspberry-pi, python-requests

So i have been creating a python code that calls to an [API](https://stats.foldingathome.org/api/donor/PointofHorizon) to get its JSON code.

After requesting the api with this code:

```
url = requests.get("https://stats.foldingathome.org/api/donor/PointofHorizon")
```

I then would print out the given JSON information into the console to get this output:

```
{"wus": 131, "rank": 99964, "total_users": 2236318, "active_50": 2, "path": "donor/PointofHorizon", "wus_cert": "https://apps.foldingathome.org/awards?user=35025837&type=wus", "id": 35025837, "credit_cert": "https://apps.foldingathome.org/awards?user=35025837&type=score", "last": "2020-03-22 15:18:54", "name": "PointofHorizon", "teams": [{"wus": 97, "last": "2020-03-22 15:18:54", "uid": 35025837, "active_50": 2, "active_7": 2, "credit": 310435, "team": 225605, "name": "PC Master Race - PCMR"}, {"wus": 34, "last": "2019-08-17 13:00:11", "uid": 35025837, "active_50": 0, "active_7": 0, "credit": 431809, "team": 223518, "name": "LinusTechTips_Team"}], "active_7": 2, "credit": 742244}
```

This works perfectly running the python code on a windows machine but if I were to run this exact python code on a Raspberry Pi I would get the JSON but it would be completely randomized.
Note that both windows and the Pi are running the exact same code and windows is giving me the output I want just pi is not. Can anyone explain why I am getting randomizes outputs on the Pi compared to windows?

Here are some screenshots of the python code running 3 times on both windows and Pi so you can see what I mean by random. But basically it's taking the information from the API on the pi and not displaying the JSON file in the correct order that it is on the API page:

Windows:
edit: Python version for this windows is Python 3.8.2
[image: Windows Python code output]

Raspberry Pi:

[image: Raspberry Pi output]

Comment: Could you add what version of python you are running on windows ?

Comment: sorry added it to the question but its 3.8.2

Comment: If by "randomized" you mean that the keys are not in  the same order (sorry, I will NOT try to compare two images of code), then it's due to Python 3.8x dicts being ordered while they weren't in previous versions. This is an implementation detail, and actually totally irrelevant since the json spec clearly states that json objects are *unordered* collections of key=>values, so you shouldn't rely on the keys ordering anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an expected behavior: the [JSON standard](https://www.json.org/json-en.html)  states :

> An object is an unordered set of name/value pairs.

Hence there is no "correct" or "incorrect" order of the resulting JSON.

As why the order does not change on Windows, but it changes on the Raspberry Pi, it is because you run different version of Python. Since Python 3.7, dict are now ordered and preserve the order of insertion.

If you want a consistent result, run the same version of python on both machines. You could also consider using an [OrderedDict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), or sort (using `sorted(json_response)`) the resulting dictionary, if the order really matters to you.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are observing that in `python3.5`, there are no guarantees on the order of keys in a dictionary. The JSON string returned by your API is probably the same (after all, it comes from the same server). However, when `python` converts it to a dictionary, it does not respect the order of keys.

If you want to keep this information, consider upgrading to python3.7+, where dictionary order is now deterministic (see [release notes](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.7.html) )